# Put server passwords in environment variable

Tags: centos, password, environment-variables

Iam wondering, if it would be safe to put server variables as an environment variable in a `~/.bash_profile`. Iam on a CentOS 6 shared host webserver. The passwords for the databases are currently available in `.my.cnf` and `.my.mariadb.cnf`. Would there be any security disadvantage, when I put them to `.bash_profile` as environment variables?

Comment: why not use mariadb pam auth module?  if all 3 files have the same permission bit I don't see how they're more/less secure from each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as filesystem permissions are concerned, you should certainly make sure that your `.bash_profile` (and your other config with passwords) has mode 0600.

You should bear in mind that *any* processes you then run from bash will have these credentials set in their environment. That means that if, for example, you run something that dumps the environment to a log file for debugging then that file reveals your passwords. Depending on your use case it might be safer to have another file, say `~/passwords.sh` that you can read with `source ~/passwords.sh`, or a shorter alias, when you know you need it.

As a general rule it's good to have plain-text passwords available in as few locations as possible.

Comment: I see that envVars are not a very good idea. originally my attempt was to use the var for short mysql shell commands like `mysql -h "localhost" -u "$MYSQL_USER" "-p$MYSQL_PASS" ...` Iam unsure how to achieve that now

Comment: oh hell, is not necessary because mysql takes it itself from the my.cnf, to stupid easy